# How can I set up a new Outlook.com account using a Hotmail account?

Tags: email

How can I setup a new outlook.com account in the Android mail application?

Outlook.com only supports Exchange ActiveSync, when I try to automatically create an account in the mail app it uses smtp.live.com (because my login is a hotmail account).

What should I change the server settings to in order to use outlook.com's exchange servers?

I am using a Sony Xperia P which is currently stuck on Android 2.3.7. It appears to support Exchange ActiveSync.

Comment: Specifying your device may actually be relevant here (though I'm not sure). Some manufacturers have had poor support for Exchange in their email applications in the past. Most notably, [Motorola essentially broke it with an update once](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/tech-issues-bug-reports-suggestions/77812-exchange-email-not-working-after-update.html).

Comment: Yes, you should specify device and os version. I can add my Ms account on CM9 and it uses exchange.

Comment: I have updated the post with my phone. @RichardBorcsik you can add an outlook.com account using a hotmail.com login?

Comment: Yes. In fact that's the only way I can add it, because if I try it with an `@outlook.com` alias, it complains that there's no such account on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manually setup an Exchange ActiveSync account with the following settings:

```
Domain: *blank*  
Username: myname@hotmail.com 
Password: ***********
Server: snt-m.hotmail.com 
Use secure connection (SSL): *checked* 
Accept all SSL Certificates: *unchecked*
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Use the settings below for your outlook.com account.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]